Having problem defining the order of an amplitude function
I am reading about pseudo-differential operators and can't seem to wrap my head around defining the order of an amplitude function. Here are the definitions I use:
Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be open, $m\in\mathbb{R}$ and $N\in \mathbb{N}\cup\{0\}=:\mathbb{Z}_+$. Denote by $S^m$ the set of all functions $a\in C^\infty (\Omega \times \mathbb{R}^N)$ so that for every compact set $K\Subset \mathbb{R}$ and arbitrary multi-indices $\alpha \in \mathbb{Z}_+^N$, $\beta \in \mathbb{Z}_+^n$ there is a constant $c=c_{\alpha,\beta,K}>0$ such that
$$|D_x^\beta D_\xi^\alpha a(x,\xi)|\leq c(1+|\xi|)^{m-|\alpha|} \text{ for all } x\in K \text{ and } \xi \in \mathbb{R}^N.$$
The order of $a$, denoted by $Ord(a)$, is the smallest possible $m\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $a\in S^m$. Note that for $m<l$ we have $S^m \subset S^l$.
My attempt to define the order is by
$$Ord(a)=\min\{m\in\mathbb{R}|a\in S^m\}.$$ But I am having difficulty proving that the minimum exists (of course $Ord(a)=-\infty$ if $a\in S^m$ for all $m$). What I tried is to set $\lambda=\inf\{m\in\mathbb{R}|a\in S^m\}$. Then for every $\epsilon>0$ we have $a\in S^{\lambda + \epsilon}$. For $\alpha,\beta,K$ set $c_{\alpha,\beta,K,\epsilon}$ as the corresponding constant. Note as $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$ we can expect $c_{\alpha,\beta,K,\epsilon}$ to grow. Then, I think, the inequality above holds (for the fixed $\alpha,\beta, K$ and $m=\lambda$) iff $\{ c_{\alpha,\beta, K,\epsilon} \}_{\epsilon>0}$ is bounded. But I am not sure how to prove it is bounded. I tried to estimate how fast it needs to grow, but I think I am missing something. Probably something more fundamental.
If you have any idea it would be great. Thank you very much.
